# Assistance with finding the accumulation points for $(3,6) \cup (6,9]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble digesting the definition of an accumulation point(s).  Can you help me to understand it given the following:

> $(3,6) \cup (6,9]$

I know this produces the interior set $(3;9]\backslash \{6\}$

The definition I have states that:

> Let S be a subset of $\mathbb R$. A point $x$ in $\mathbb R$ is an accumulation point of S iff every deleted neighborhood of x contains a point of S

The way I read that tells me that $6$ is an accumlation point because every point around $6$ is in S.

Comment: Assuming your set is considered as a subset of $\mathbb R$, then every point in $[3,9]$ is an accumulation point (by your definition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, $9$ is not an interior point, as every neighbourhood of $9$ contains a set of the form $(9-r,9+r)$ which is not contained in $A = (3,6] \cup (6,9]$, as it contains points larger than $9$.

Indeed $6$ is an accumulation point, as a neighbourhood of $6$ contains a set of the form $(6-a,6+a)$, so intersects $A$ on both sides of $6$.

We also have $3$ (and $9$) as accumulation points, for similar reasons. Also, interior points of $A$ are (in the reals!) also accumulation points.

If $x < 3$ then $(\leftarrow,3)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ which misses the set $A$ under discussion, so also a deleted neighbourhood of $x$ does not contain a point of $A$, and the same can be said for all $x > 9$ using the neighbourhood $(9,\rightarrow)$. So the set of accumulation points is $[3,9]$.

Comment: So my interior set is actually $(3,9)\backslash\{6\}$ since $9+r$ takes me outside of A?

Comment: @free_mind indeed. You need to stay totally inside.